# Кнопка в html работает а в php уже нет

Tags: javascript, php, html

не работает код кнопки передающий данные таблици в pdf  в файле который с расширением html работает, а вот уже в php нет в чем может быть проблема?

```
<p class="lead"><button id="pdf" class="btn btn-danger">Сохранить в PDF</button></p>
    </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.5/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
      <script src="tableHTMLExport.js"></script>
      <script>

          $("#pdf").on('click',function(){
              $("#example").tableHTMLExport({type:'pdf',filename:'sample.pdf'});
          })
      </script>
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click',"#pdf",function(){//TO DO});`

Comment: тут в принципе нигде php не упоминается, поэтому и не работает.

Comment: @Gy9vin как именно кнопка добавляется у вас? И сколько их на странице, одна?

Comment: @InDevX в коде указано как она добовляется `<button id="pdf" class="btn btn-danger">Сохранить в PDF</button>`

Comment: @Gy9vin скиньте полностью код php страницы вашей (в тему добавьте)

Comment: php страницу сервер обрабатывает. Она не должна в браузере работать напрямую.

Comment: Ужа разобрался, пришлось переписать страницу заново и стало работать)